# Test for equality between a clojure PersistentArrayMap and a datomic EntityMap?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm writing some tests on my datomic code. I create a transaction map:

```
(def tx-map
  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -1000235]
   :some-ns/my-attr {:db/id 17592186045421}}
```

It transacts fine. I query for my newly added entity:

```
 (def ent
   "Query result."
   {:db/id 17592186045425})
```

Test to see if all is well:

```
(= (:some-ns/my-attr tx-map) ; {:db/id 17592186045421}
   (:some-ns/my-attr ent))   ; {:db/id 17592186045421}

=> false ; All is not well
```

The reason being?

```
(type (:some-ns/my-attr tx-map)) => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
(type (:some-ns/my-attr ent))    => datomic.query.EntityMap
```

How do I correctly test for equality between a clojure PersistentArrayMap and a datomic EntityMap?

Comment: There's some errors. In the test and the type check `(:some-ns/my-attr ent)` will return nil, as `ent` is `{:db/id 17592186045425}`.

Comment: And the type results are exchanged.

Comment: There's something I don't understand in this code, you should give exactly what you get with your query... ;)

Comment: tx-map is the query, why do you compare the query and... ? the result of the query ? no,it's hard coded... where is the query result ?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't assume you can test for equality when comparing Clojure objects with Java objects. See http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1036 for more details.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you expect the semantics of the equality to be? Just the same id is fine? If so, you have a satisfactory (and fairly simple) answer already (:db/id). If not, do you want entities of a different basis-t to be equal/unequal intrinsicially or conditionally (e.g. only on attribute, value changes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities are lazy maps, so they cannot be compared with maps.
http://docs.datomic.com/entities.html

But they are associative and we can get the values for each attributes. So you can compare the `id`s :

```
(== (:db/id (:some-ns/my-attr tx-map)) ; 17592186045421
    (:db/id ent))                      ; 17592186045421
```

Beware the `==`, we compare two numbers... ;)

So only the `:db/id` will be selected. Perhaps the `ent` function should give you the `id`.

```
(def ent
  ":db/id of query result."
  17592186045425)
```

And the test becomes :

```
(== (:db/id (:some-ns/my-attr tx-map)) ; 17592186045421
    ent)                               ; 17592186045421
```

Sorry for the late answer, I was very buzy.

Warning, it's only according to the documentation, I don't have an runnable installed datomic version now...

Answer (score 0):

Assoc'ing and the other Clojure map interface capabilities aren't currently supported on Datomic EntityMaps, but this feature is under consideration.

To convert an entity to a Clojure map, simply use (into).

(into {} some-entity)

Reference : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/datomic/IzRSK9e7VJo/YGejFLl3vxYJ

But it's not the problem here, as this gives the whole attributes that would be returned if we realize the whole map.

Comment: Unfortunately if I use `into` on `{:db/id 17592186045421}`, the EID gets expanded into a full attr/val map of that entity.